# How does one load a different html page from the same Express controller script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I want to change the first page *(login page)*, after some defined action has been performed on it, with a second page *(admin dashboard)* from the same controller in Express.

Here's my controller code from `nimda.js` that matters:

```
function handlePut(req, res){
    let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/feed.html'));
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
}

router.put('/', handlePut);

// This handles the form submitted.
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.pwd != '1234')
        res.send('False');
    else
        {
            //Doesn't work from here.
            handlePut(req, res);
        }
});

//This is when server.js routes the request to this script
router.get('/', function( req, res){
    let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/login_nimda.html'));
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});
```

I thought that doing a PUT from my POST code after authentication would help me send a new HTML page as a response. The first HTML page is `login_nimda.html` that does the **POST** request to `/nimda`.
This doesn't work and I stay on the same `login_nimda.html`. The POST request works properly though.

Here's the script of my `login_nimda.html`:

```
<script>
 $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        var form = $('#log').serialize();

        $.post('/nimda', form).done(function(data) {
                if(data=="False" && $('#err').length==0){
                    $('#log').prepend('<p id = "err" class = "alert alert-info" align = "centre" > Incorrect!</p>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#err').remove();
                    document.location.href = '/nimda/'+data;  
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

Any alternatives to this approach are most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I could come up with two totally non-secure ways-

**1. Passing the password as method information post authentication**

The script under `login_nimda.html` is modified to send a request to the same controller `nimda.js`:

```
$.post('/nimda', form).done(function(data) {
    if (data == "False" && $('#err').length == 0) {
        $('#log').prepend('<p id = "err" class = "alert alert-info" align = "centre" > Incorrect!</p>');
    } else {
        $('#err').remove();
        document.location.href = '/nimda/'+$('input[type="password"]').val();  
    }
});
```

Since the password will be present in the URL only post successful authentication, only an authorized user would see it - *Downside: The password with the URL gets cached*

`nimda.js` is modified to load the "second page":

```
//the handler I added
router.get('/your_password', function(req, res){
    let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/second_page.html'));
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//for login authentication
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.pwd != '1234')
        res.send('False');
    else
        res.send('True');
});
```

**2. Passing a random string to the controller in the method information post authentication**

*Hmmm, I've no better option currently*

The script under `login_nimda.html` is modified to send a request to the same controller `nimda.js` but this time, not passing the password *but a random string received post authentication as an access key*:

```
<script>
 $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        var form = $('#log').serialize();

        $.post('/nimda', form).done(function(data) {
                if(data=="False" && $('#err').length==0){
                    $('#log').prepend('<p id = "err" class = "alert alert-info" align = "centre" > Incorrect!</p>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#err').remove();
                    document.location.href = '/nimda/'+data;  
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

`nimda.js` is modified to add a new route handler **only every time authentication is successful** with the route `/nimda/new_random_string` and the key (`new_random_string`) is passed as a response so that the control moves to the new handler to display the second page:

```
var key = '';

function createRandomString( length ) {
    var str = "";
    for ( ; str.length < length; str += Math.random().toString( 36 ).substr( 2 ) );
    key = str.substr( 0, length );
    return key;
}

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.pwd != '1234')
        res.send('False');
    else
        {
            router.get('/'+ createRandomString(16), function(req, res){
            let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/feed.html'));
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(html);
            });
            res.send(key);
        }
});
```

This way the key can changes with every request and so cache is rendered useless.
Please let me know a better solution. I know there is!

Comment: Why do you consider the second way "non-secure"? (the first one definitely is of course).

Comment: I don't know I just felt like it isn't secure. Is it?

Comment: The principle seems sound to me, it is actually similar to the way session cookies work.

Answer (score 2):

When you send your POST request in JavaScript, you are in the browser (client side). The response to that request will be received by the browser, as text data, containing HTML or whatever the server sent.

If as a response to the data you received in JavaScript you want to move to another page, you must do that in JavaScript.

In JavaScript you will use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location):

```
$.post('/nimda', form).done(function(data) {
    if (data == "False" && $('#err').length == 0) {
        $('#log').prepend('<p id = "err" class = "alert alert-info" align = "centre" > Incorrect!</p>');
    } else {
        $('#err').remove();
        document.location.href = '/some-page.html';  
    }
});
```

Comment: Umm, I do not want to expose the name of `some-page.html`. I would rather want the control to move inside the controller after the authentication in the POST method and then be sending the second HTML file from there.

Comment: The server cannot force the browser to load another resource. If you don't want to expose your redirect page then redirect to `/whatever.html` and then let the server serve the page you want or redirect to another page. Either way, once the page is loaded you cannot prevent the user from knowing the URL.